# Multiple if statements work unless the value is null

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Haven't done a lot of php/mysql but this seems like it should be an easy fix I am probably just screwing something small up.  Sorry for the long explanation wanted to be thorough

I have a mysql database full of fitness testing results and there is a page on the site that displays the results of the logged in person.

There is specific data called balance symmetry that our equipment collects and the result is either a positive or negative percentage.  If a person has -15% symmetry or less they need extra work on their left leg and if they are +15% symmetry or less they need more work on their right leg.

This is a very important factor so I am trying to let them know with a "red flag" at the top of the page.  The data is stored in the database as either a negative number or a positive number.

I basically want the code to do this:

```
- if the data is >= 15 then it spits out that they need more work on their right leg
- if the data is <= -15 then it spits out that they need more work on their left leg
- if the data is anything else, so between -14 and 14, or if it is null (sometimes they may not have done the balance part of the fitness test due to injury) then nothing is displayed
```

The way it works with the code below is

```
- if >= 15 works perfectly tells them to work on their right leg
- if <= -15 works perfectly tells them to work on their left leg
- if between -14 and 14 works perfectly tells them nothing
- if null tells them to work on their left leg for some reason.  how do I make it so that the null value is handled the same way as the values between -14 and 14
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if ($row['field_symmetry_value'] >= 15){
echo "              <div class='train_row1'>
           <div class='train_row_inside'>
            <div class='train_column1rf'><img src='http://racebattlerecover.com/images/redflag.png' /></div>
            <div class='train_column3rf'><h3>IMPORTANT: Your balance symmetry between your left and right leg is off by more than 15%. You need to add extra balance exercises to your right leg.</h3></div>
           </div>
          </div>";
}
elseif ($row['field_symmetry_value'] <= -15){
echo "              <div class='train_row1'>
           <div class='train_row_inside'>
            <div class='train_column1rf'><img src='http://racebattlerecover.com/images/redflag.png' /></div>
            <div class='train_column3rf'><h3>IMPORTANT: Your balance symmetry between your left and right leg is off by more than 15%. You need to add extra balance exercises to your left leg.</h3></div>
           </div>
          </div>";
}

?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not just test initially for `null` value and error/exception out (or cancel the output)?

Comment: Also, take a look at the [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), since PHP is not strong-typed in it's checking.

Comment: Having it initially testing for null worked.  I had tried putting it at the end as another elseif statement which didn't work but when I put it in as the original if statement it works perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: What you really need to do is test if it's (not) a numeric value first, then test the left/right value. If I add that as an answer, will you upvote and mark as the answer?

Comment: Ya that sounds like a good way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but for some reason `null` is considered to be less than -15.  I would think  `null` would be treated like 0 in numeric comparisons, but apparently not.  You can fix this pretty easily:

```
else if (!is_null($row['field']) && $row['field'] <= -15) {
```

You can also do this check in the query:

```
COALESCE(field_symmetry_value, 0)
```

This will return 0 if `field_symmetry_value` is `NULL`, which won't print anything.